# Save new spread sheet with data's date in name

Tags: vba, excel

I want to save a file that I download from the internet with the name of the month the data is from in the file name.  The issue I come across is I cant get just the month. I get the whole date in the mm/dd/yyy format in VBA.  The date is in the mm/dd/yyy h:mm format in the worksheet.  I want to convert this to just that month so I have put the month in the file name and saved it.  VBA sees it as a mm/dd/yyy so it can not be added to the file name.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Given `Range("A1")` holds the date you want to get the month for, write this:

```
Dim myDate as String
myDate = Format(Range("A1"),"mmmm"))
```

Answer (score 0):

using today as an example,

```
Dim myDate as String
' if you want to get November 
myDate = monthname(month(date))  
'or 
myDate = Format(date,"mmmm")

'if you want to get 11
myDate = month(date) 

'if you want to get Nov
myDate = Format(date, "mmm")
' or LEFT the November to 3 characters
```